# MdiParent property of child forms

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to do some practices on a MDI application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 but it seems that I'm doing something wrong.

I made a new **Windows Forms Application** project and changed the **IsMdiContainer** property of the first form to **True**. Then I add a new form by right clicking the project in solution explorer and selecting **Add - New Item - Windows Form**.

I'm trying to set **MdiParent** property of form2 to the MDI Container form, but it seems that form2 has no **MdiParent** property.
Here's the properties of form2 sorted alphabetically.

[image]

Of course I can open form2 as a child form this way:

```
form2 newMDIChild = new form2();
newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
newMDIChild.Show();
```

I just wondered why the forms has no **MDIParent** property.
According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx)  the child forms have a **MdiParent** property.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it right, instantiating the new form and assigning `MdiParent` there. Really there IS such a property, and in your code you're using it:

```
newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
```

This is perfectly fine and the normal way of doing it.

Now, what you're pointing is that the designer doesn't shows it, which is also true. That don't means that the property don't exist (it does, and you're using it in fact!). Why it isn't in the designer property sheet is another history, totally irrelevant, but I suppose that it has to do with the fact that it's difficult, if not impossible to properly set `MdiParent` at design time. If you think about it, it must contain an instance of another form (with it's `IsMdiContainer` set to `true`). At design time, you don't have any instances of anything, as they're created as your program runs. There is no way that you can set it beforehand, as you must normally pass another form to it, which you can't know while designing.